# How to start multiple graphic sessions?

Tags: linux, shell, ssh, osx

I need to test my application on a friend's mac. Not to disturb him, I thought I could connect me to his PC through SSH (with -X option), but to avoid opening the app in his session, a new session has to be started on his pc... Can this idea work? And if yes, how can I do it?

Comment: In mac's preferences, look for sharing -> remote desktop. And consider using a separate user.

Answer (score 2):

no. By doing `ssh -X`, the windows will be opened in *your* local session and the user on remote host will not even notice.

By connecting using `ssh` (even with forwarding X11) you don't open any graphical session on remote host, but the application run there are running on X-Server which is on your own computer.

Comment: Once connected to remote PC with ssh -X, if I start xeyes (for example), it starts in my pc, but if I try to start MyApplication or Safari or others, I get error... Once connected, probably, I should start a Graphic Session before starting programs... From terminal, if I launch startx then I get errors

Comment: No, you don't want to call `startx` over ssh. I don't want to say it is not possible, but it is not the way how does X11 forwarding work, as described above. It is for launching separate window applications. If you want whole *DE, you should look for VNC.

Comment: Ok, I understand. I'll try VNC... Sorry for my English